# How do you solve $3^x=9\cdot27$?

Tags: operator-theory

I don't understand how to calculate the following expression $3^x=9\cdot27$.

Thank you a lot for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $9=3^2$ and $27=3^3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply re-write $9\cdot 27=3^2\cdot 3^3 $. Hence, it gives $3^5$. Therefore $3^x=3^5$ implies $x=5$.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now.